# Какой класс надо импортировать для дебага стрима?

Tags: java-stream

Пробую запустить такой код, но debug и doSomeStaff идея подчеркивает красным.Для doSomeStaff вариантов импорта не предлагает.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        numbers.stream()
                .peek(n -> debug(n))
                .forEach(n -> doSomeStaff(n));
```

Comment: Судя по поведению Идеи эти методы не имеют реализации в вашем коде? Вы скопировали код с некого ресурса?

Comment: Что такое `debug` и `doSomeStaff`?

Comment: это не [отсюда](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-8-stream-debug/)?

Comment: да, с того ресурса

Comment: это просто пример, вы должны реализовать методы `debug` и `doSomeStaff` сами